# How to use wait_for

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I'm making a bot and I'm not sure how to use the wait_for command. I'm trying to have the bot wait for a response and check if that response is a link. Here's the code.

```
@client.command()
async def begin(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Please send the link to the homepage of your server hosting site.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the coroutine [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for), basically it waits for the user to reply with a message on a specific time lapse `timeout`. In this example I used part of @Dj Walkzz code.

```py
@client.command()
async def begin(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Please send the link to the homepage of your server hosting site.")
    
    #Creates a check that checks the user and channel
    def check(r):
        return ctx.author == r.author and ctx.channel == r.channel

    #Waits for the message to be sent, if it exceeds 25 seconds it exits out
    msg = await client.wait_for("message",check=check,timeout=25)

    #Checks if message is a link (Not the best solution, use requests or regex)
    if ("http" in msg.content):
        #Do Stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait_for code :

```py
def check(m):
   return ctx.author == m.author 
msg = await client.wait_for("message",check=check,timeout=10)
```

The `msg` here is discord.Message means u can use it as normal message like `msg.author` , `msg.content` etc.

Comment: how would i check to see if the response is a link? and if it is, how would i move on with the command?

Comment: Just use a if "http" in msg.content.lower():

Comment: for a more robust solution use regex